# crawl urls from sitemap and index it to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scrapy, web-crawler, nutch, frontera

I have a use case where i need to crawl pages from bunch of sitemap and index it to elasticsearch. From my investigation so far I have narrowed it down to Nutch and Scrapy (may be Frontera). I like Nutch because it is very mature and it has integration with Tika and other libraries so that parsing different types of content (like PDF, Doc, etc) would be possible. I read some good things about Scrapy as well and wondering whether it would be a good choice. I am looking for something thats widely adopted and fairly stable. I am highly familiar with Java but i am familiar with Python as well.

I would be curious to hear any experience or recommendation from people who have used one of the above mentioned tools.

Comment: Any reason you did not consider StormCrawler? It supports sitemaps, Elasticsearch and has a plugin for Tika. It is actively maintained and implemented in Java.

Comment: I glanced over it and it said its not a full fledged crawler but an SDK. May be an SDK will do the job for me as well, as i am just exploring i dont really know the answer. I am also worried about adoption and active maintenance. But if you had good experience with it, I would be glad to hear about it as well.

Comment: it can be fully fledged and an SDK at the same time. Scrapy is an SDK too if I am not mistaken. Re-active maintenance : release cycle between 1 and 2 months + frequent commits. Note : I am the author of SC and of course am a bit biased